# json array return a empty array

Tags: json, express

I am get some Json object from Youtube api. Now, when I was going to read a array object then it's return a empty array.

code->

```
res.on("data",function(data){
    const da=JSON.parse(data);
   const ku=da.items;
    console.log(ku);
});
```

Output->[Return an empty array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCbOx.png)

Json obeject->[Json object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h90co.jpg)

Then, **How to read the array with nested object in array?**.
Please,help.

Comment: Looks like the API call changed and you don't get any result. Please share more info about how you are calling the API.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the http or https module to make the request then you have to append the data chunks and on the event "end" you can actually parse the data to JSON and process it

try something like this

```
    let str = ''
    res.on('data', chunk => { str += chunk }
    res.on('end', () => {
        let json = JSON.parse(str)
        console.log(json.items)
    }
```